# How does all traffic go through wireguard?

Tags: routing, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to understand how all traffic on my machine gets routed through wireguard when I connect to a wiregurad VPN. See outputs below of `ip route` `ip a s`, and `ip rule`.

My VPN was set up using my provider's CLI tool with `mullvad connect` after installing the tool and associating it with my account: https://mullvad.net/en/help/how-use-mullvad-cli

My understanding from the routing table says that anything from source 192.168.44.83 on dev wlp0s20f3 is destined to default. But I can't seem to see how that traffic ends up on the wiregurad network interface. How does that happen?

```
$ ip -c route
default via 192.168.44.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 192.168.44.83 metric 600 
10.64.0.1 dev wg-mullvad proto static 
192.168.44.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.44.83 metric 600 


$ ip -c rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0x6d6f6c65 lookup 1836018789
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default


$ ip -c a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:20:ff:a7:68:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.44.83/24 brd 192.168.44.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 259023sec preferred_lft 259023sec
    inet6 fe80::9f4e:c306:9e3d:8e8/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: wg-mullvad: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1380 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.147.23.252/32 scope global wg-mullvad
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output from `ip route show table 1836018789`:

```
$ ip route show table 1836018789
default dev wg-mullvad proto static
```

Output from `nft list ruleset`:

```
# nft list ruleset
table inet mullvad {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -199; policy accept;
        iif != "wg-mullvad" ct mark 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
        ip saddr 185.195.233.76 udp sport 19955 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
        oif "lo" accept
        ct mark 0x00000f41 accept
        udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff02::1:2 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff05::1:3 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::2 icmpv6 type nd-router-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::1:ff00:0/104 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip daddr 185.195.233.76 udp dport 19955 meta mark 0x6d6f6c65 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        udp dport 53 reject
        tcp dport 53 reject with tcp reset
        oif "wg-mullvad" accept
        reject
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept
        ct mark 0x00000f41 accept
        udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 547 ip6 daddr fe80::/10 udp dport 546 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-router-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-redirect icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip saddr 185.195.233.76 udp sport 19955 ct state established accept
        iif "wg-mullvad" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        ct mark 0x00000f41 accept
        udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
        udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff02::1:2 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff05::1:3 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 547 ip6 daddr fe80::/10 udp dport 546 accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::2 icmpv6 type nd-router-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-router-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-redirect icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::1:ff00:0/104 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        udp dport 53 reject
        tcp dport 53 reject with tcp reset
        oif "wg-mullvad" accept
        iif "wg-mullvad" ct state established accept
        reject
    }

    chain mangle {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        meta cgroup 5087041 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
    }

    chain nat {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oif "wg-mullvad" ct mark 0x00000f41 drop
        oif != "lo" ct mark 0x00000f41 masquerade
    }
}
```

Comment: if you didn't configure routes and/or masquerading accordingly, it does *not* happen. Wireguard itself only fulfills the "encrypted, authenticated tunnel" part of a VPN. The part of a VPN that routes traffic through that tunnel needs to be set up separately. Did you set it up separately?

Comment: I set it up using my VPN provider's CLI tool. I believe connecting using the tool sets it up https://mullvad.net/en/help/how-use-mullvad-cli

Comment: please add that info to your question (by editing it!). Tell us exactly how you set it up, we can't guess that.

Comment: You probably missed `ip rule` pointing to an additional routing table: it uses policy routing when overriding the default route.

Comment: Next step: `ip route show table 1836018789` + `wg show wg-mullvad fwmark` + `nft list ruleset`. We're getting there.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Do you know what a VPN does? Tunnels etc?

Comment: thanks for showing those commands @A.B

Comment: Is it really *all* network traffic, or only FTP/HTTP(S) traffic, that goes through the wg interface? I see that the mullvad CLI tool can also set up system-wide proxying. Is it possible that the observed behavior is not due to routing but to proxying? You can inspect ```env | grep -i proxy``` to reveal any system-wide proxy configuration. You could also try either *wget* or *curl* with the ```--no-proxy``` switch and see if that traffic gets routed through wg interface as well.

Comment: Looks like mullvad does additional things beyond WG's wg-quick. The base part is described there: https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#rule-based-routing . I give up for the what remains.